# The memory leak caused by `sd_setImage` which is from SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: deviceGuideGif, ofType: "gif")!
let url:URL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path)
imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
```

I add this code to a viewController(Let's call it VC1). And when I push VC1 from other viewController,the Memory Use increased.After that, I pop VC1 and the Memory Use didn't decrease.
Now there is a memory leak and I don't know how this happened.Is this a wrong way to use `SDWebImage` or is there any bugs in SDWebImage?

[image: Memory Use]

PS:

It works well if I use this code:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: deviceGuideGif, ofType: "gif")!
let url:URL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path)
let imageData = try?Data.init(contentsOf: url)
let image = UIImage.sd_image(with: imageData)
imageView.image = image
```